# Two smooth tangent almost complex curves in a $4$-manifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

I would like to know if following is correct.

**Statement.** Suppose we have a smooth (i.e., $C^\infty$) almost  complex structure on $\mathbb R^4$ and $C_1, C_2$ are two $J$-holomorphic curves passing through $(0,0)$, tangent at $(0,0)$ and regular at $(0,0)$. Then there exist $C^{\infty}$ smooth complex coordinates $(z,w)$ such that $C_1$ is locally given by $w=0$ and $C_2$ by $w=z^n$.

PS. I think it would be enough for me to know that $C_2$ can be given by $w=z^n+O|z^{n+1}|$. However everything must be $C^{\infty}$ - the coordinates, and the $O|z^{n+1}|$ term. If, on the other hand one can not expect to have a $C^{\infty}$ diffeo, what is the best one can expect?

Comment: It should follow from Lemma 1.2.2 in McDuff's *"Singularities and positivity of intersections of J-holomorphic curves"* that we can find such coordinates except that $C_2$ is locally $w=z^n+O(|z|^{n+1})$. I'm not sure we have enough freedom to get rid of the higher order terms, unless you perturb $C_2$ (but try McDuff's other related papers on local properties of $J$-holomorphic curves).

Comment: Dear Chris, thank you for your comment. I had a look into Lemma 1.2.2. Unfortunately, I don't see how one deduces from Lemma 1.2.2 what you are claiming...(Is this something written in the beginning of the proof of Lemma 1.3.1?) In fact, if you could give me a more less explicit reference to the statement that you give it will be very useful.

Comment: Chris, I don't understand what you mean by *multiply covered*. Both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are smooth, and I just consider them as surfaces embedded in $\mathbb R^4$ (so why speak about multiply covered?)

Comment: Typically in J-holomorphic theory, “curve” means map, whereas if we just care about the image we say “surface” or “subvariety”. So based on what you’re looking for, I’m just writing $C_2$ as a graph of $C_1$ as in McDuff’s paper.

Comment: Thanks for explaining Chris. I corrected the formulation of the question, hope that it is clear now what I mean. If I understand correctly what you write you can answer the weaker version of this question (with the term $O|z|^{n+1}$). Would you be so kind to write this down as an answer (and not just a comment)?

Comment: This formulation is similar (if not the same) to the Micallef-White paper, so I do not know if everything can be done $C^\infty$ (but it is at least true for $C^2$). I can still post this with detail as a semi-answer if you want. Everything might be OK for $C^\infty$, and the very useful references on your question are: Appendix E (*"Singularities and intersections"*) of McDuff-Salamon's big book *"J-holomorphic curves and symplectic topology"*, and McDuff's paper *"The local behavior of holomorphic curves in almost complex 4-manifolds"*, both of which stem from the Micallef-White paper.

Comment: I see. Well, I need a $C^{\infty}$ statement...

Comment: Does Lemma 3.4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9907155.pdf give you what you want?

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the reference. I had a look. Unfortunately it is a bit heavy, so I can not understand so far if this is what I want... In case there is any ambiguity in what I want, I put a twins version of this question, formulated in a slightly different form - in case there is an uncertainty with this formulation..: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296679/normal-form-of-two-tangent-symplectic-surfaces-in-mathbb-r4

Comment: @DanielPomerleano That's just a reformulation of McDuff's statements that I reference (which subsequently refer to Micallef-White).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This follows from theorem 6.2 (and the first sentence in the proof) of Mario J. Micallef and Brian White, *The structure of branch points in minimal surfaces and in pseudoholomorphic curves*, **Ann. of Math.** (2) 141 (1995), no. 1, 35–85.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Ben! I had a look. The theorem that you cite is speaking about $C^2$ and $C^1$ diffeos. At the same time I want a smooth -- $C^{\infty}$ diffeo. It is not clear for me if the article answers my question, unfortunately. Is this the case?

Comment: @aglearner: I am sorry, I don't know.

Comment: In case you're interested, Appendix E (written by Lazzarini) in McDuff-Salamon's book clarifies the differentiability issues.

Comment: I guess, I'll need to buy the book, it is not in our library. In the end maybe $C^2$ or $C^1$ diffeo is enough... But it would be nice to have an example where $C^{\infty}$ diffeo does not exist.

Comment: I'll accept the answer, since it helped me to answer the question that I needed to answer (with the error term) and prompted a useful discussion

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that it is nice to read books. The answer to the weaker version of my question with $O|z|^{n+1}$ term is contained on page 17 of McDuff-Salamon book [MS] (no need of Micallef-White!):
https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/jholsm.pdf

**Proof.** In the proof of Lemma 2.2.3 of [MS] one uses coordinates in $\mathbb C^2$ such that $C_1$ is given by $w=0$ and the almost complex structure $J$ along the line $(z,0)$ is the standard one. Then it is explained that the almost complex map $z\to \mathbb C^2$ corresponding to $C_2$ is given by

$$z\to (p(z)+O(|z^{n+1}|), az^n+O(|z^{n+1}|))$$

where $p(z)$ is a polynomial of order at most $n$, $a\ne 0$. In our case of course $p'(0)\ne 0$. It is now clear that in these coordinates $C_2$ is as need. **QED.**

**Comment.** The above proof is elementary and does not use Micallef-White. Similarly to Micallef-White's, statement it can be used to answer the original question with a $C^1$-smooth change of coordinates (instead of $C^{\infty}$). Indeed, after a smooth reparameterization in $z$ and scaling in $w$ the above map for $C_2$ looks as
$$z\to (z, z^n+O(|z^{n+1}|)).$$
Denote the second term by $f(z)$. Then the map
$(z,w)\to (z,w-(f(z)-z^n)/z^n)$ is $C^1$ and it sends the couple $C_1,C_2$ to the couple $(w=0, w=z^n)$.

I wonder still if one can make this last change of coordinates $C^{\infty}$...

Comment: This is what I wrote in my comment (following the beginning of the proof of McDuff's Lemma 1.3.1 in the quoted paper of my comment), and is just an adaptation of Micallef-White's theorem which Ben quotes in his answer; but I thought the real question was about other $C^\infty$-smooth coordinates for the images.

Comment: Chris, thanks for your comment! I am neophyte with $J$-holomorphic maps, and (partially) for this reason had a problem to understand what you've written (also, I guess the book is better written than the article). But it is great that you say that this is your reasoning, since now I know that you consider it correct. I am asking this question for a particular purpose and in the end it turned out that having this  $O|z^{n+1}|$ error is fine for me so solving it in full form is not urgent anymore for me. But  I am still curious if it is possible to kill the $O|z^{n+1}|$ term.

Comment: No worries at all -- I've been confused by the difference with choosing local coordinates for the *maps* versus just the *subspaces*, so I'm glad we're both focusing in on it. I believe we can get rid of the $O$-term by perturbing $C_2$ while preserving tangency at the origin, but if you need $C_2$ fixed then I don't know but my guess is no (there are some nice examples which may be your counterexamples at the very end of McDuff's 1992 paper *"Singularities of J-holomorphic curves in
almost complex 4-manifolds"*).

Comment: I just realized that the lemma you quote is not similar but *precisely the same* Lemma 1.3.1 of McDuff's paper I quote. This paper precedes production of those lecture notes you refer to, which by the way is an old version, the new version is the "big book" (2nd edition) that I also referenced containing Lazzarini's Appendix E.